# The use of the noun "change" in context

Tags: word-usage

Let's say I bought a phone that costs 100 dollars, and I paid 150 dollars, but the shop assistant didn't give me the change. Is it natural to say the following?

> I am sorry, but could you pay me back **the** **fifty dollar change**.

Comment: You don't ***pay back*** "change" - you just ***give*** it. But note that "change" in such contexts *only* applies if you had no choice but to pay using larger denomination coins or banknotes, which is logically impossible in your cited context (there's no such thing as a $150 banknote). If the phone cost $50 and you paid using a $100 bill, *then* you'd expect to be given $50 in "change".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No your sentence is not idiomatic. We don't use the phrase **pay back** when talking about change. It really belongs to a context in which you have loaned money to someone.

In practice you would be most unlikely to pay an additional $50 dollars. But let's overlook that. The first thing you would have to do is to explain the situation to the shop assistant.

> Excuse me. I have just bought this $100 phone from you. I see that I accidentally overpaid you by giving you a third $50 dollar note/bill. May I ask you to return it to me.

Take a more realistic situation, assuming that you bought a $90 phone with $100 note.

> Excuse me, but you haven't given me the ($10) change that you owe me. I paid for the phone with $100 note/bill and you still owe me $10 dollars.